# h5py - convert dtype from dataset from int/float to bool?

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

So to give you an idea of the structure of my data set, when I do 
print(hf["y_train"][0]) I get this as a result:
[3.2355e-05 3.3180e-05 1.0000e+00]

The values in the third column are either 1.0 or 0.0, what I'm trying to do is to convert the 1.0s to True and the 0.0s to False.

I've tried numerous things already but to no avail.

Comment: Are you trying to convert this one the file, or in the array that you've read from the file?  It might help if you described what you tried, and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a HDF5 / h5py issue. It seems the data has been stored as `float` and is being read as `float`, just as it should.

To convert to `bool` after reading, you can try [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) with the default tolerance levels:

```
A = np.array([3.2355e-05, 3.3180e-05, 1.0000e+00])

res = np.isclose(A, 1)

array([False, False,  True])
```